# Android in accessing value of a string

Tags: android

I am working on android. i want to access the file from server. if i write my url in this way:

```
URL sourceUrl = new URL("http://192.168.1.214/MusicApplication/searchsongxml.php?");
```

then it works correctly.

But if i declare the server name in **strings.xml** as follows:

```
<resources>  
    <string name="SERVER_NAME">http://192.168.1.214/</string>
</resources>
```

and try to access the url like this:

```
URL sourceUrl = new (getString(R.string.SERVER_NAME)+"MusicApplication/searchsongxml.php");
```

then this create an exception and my application halts.

Please tell me what mistake i have done.

Comment: Please post the stacktrace of your exception from `logcat`.

Comment: Unable to start activity com.pericent.musicapp.HelloTabWidget}: java.lang.NullPointerException     and this error is occurred only when i use getString(strings.R.SERVER_NAME).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
URL sourceUrl = new URL(your_context.getString(R.string.SERVER_NAME)+"MusicApplication/searchsongxml.php");
```

Comment: Ah i didn't notice that. I thought maybe some escaping issue. +1